# why PHP 403 forbidden after fresh installation on ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: server, apache2, 15.10, php, lamp

After I installed apache2 and ran it, the default HTML page of apache2 works fine. Then I installed PHP 5.6 and restarted apache2 and created PHP file in `/var/www/html` called `info.php` and put `<?php echo 'hello word!' ; ?>` in it and ran it on Firefox. As the result it says forbidden, I have tried to change the permission for `www` directory and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Post the output of `ll /var/www/html/info.php`

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 52 Apr  2 14:32 /var/www/html/info.php*
this is it.

Comment: What does the Apache error logs show are the actual cause for the 403?

Comment: the error log file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` add `Require all granted` to the directories you want to grant access to like this

```
<Directory "your directory here">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart `apache2` service and go to http://localhost/info.php .

Comment: it is already there .